# copy file with different name with phing

Tags: phing

I wrote a script in Phing that copies files for two websites, but I can't do such thing like copy file with a name change. I want to copy this image into favicon.png.

```
    <copy todir="C:\dest_folder\" >
     <fileset dir="C:\source_folder\" >
      <patternset>
        <include name="assets/ico/favicon_website1.png"/>
      </patternset>
     </fileset>
    </copy>
```

Can this be done in only one     <copy>     tag?

How can I do it?

I expect quite a few files to be copied with a changed name so I want to simplify the script.

Answer (score 5):

If it's just the one file you want to rename, use tofile rather than a fileset.

`<copy file="assets/ico/favicon_website1.png" tofile="C:\dest_folder\favicon.png" />`